# @Query (Spring data/JPA) with boolean in where condition

Tags: spring-data

SampleRepository.java class has a query like below:

```
@Query("select eq from EmailQueue eq where eq.inquiry in (select issue.id from Inquiry issue  where issue.id = eq.inquiry and systimestamp   >= eq.sendDate + (1/24) * ?3  ) and "
            + " systimestamp   >= eq.sendDate + (1/24) * ?2 and eq.sent = True and "            
            + " eq.emailType.id = ?1  "
            + "  order by eq.sendDate asc")
```

Error that i get is:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

Can you let me know how to specify the **eq.sent = True** in the @query?  I tried 
eq.sent =1 as well, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `is` instead of `=`:

```
@Query("select eq from EmailQueue eq where eq.inquiry in (select issue.id from Inquiry issue  where issue.id = eq.inquiry and systimestamp   >= eq.sendDate + (1/24) * ?3  ) and "
            + " systimestamp   >= eq.sendDate + (1/24) * ?2 and eq.sent is True and "            
            + " eq.emailType.id = ?1  "
            + "  order by eq.sendDate asc")
```

Comment: Still getting same error "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier"

Comment: i found a workaround for getting rid of this error, i will post it that.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by following workaround:

```
 @Query("select eq from EmailQueue eq where eq.inquiry in (select issue.id from Inquiry issue  where issue.id = eq.inquiry and systimestamp   >= eq.sendDate + (1/24) * ?3  ) and "
                + " systimestamp   >= eq.sendDate + (1/24) * ?2 and eq.sent = ?4 and "          
                + " eq.emailType.id = ?1  "
                + "  order by eq.sendDate asc")
List<EQueue> findEmailSentDetails(long type, int days1, int days2,boolean emailSent);
```

instead of using "eq.sent =true" pass the true as argument like **eq.sent = ?4**